# Filtering a BehaviorSubject

Tags: rxjs

I have a `BehaviorSubject` that I'd like to be able to `filter`, but maintain it's behavior-subject-like quality that new subscribers always get a value when they subscribe, even if the last value emitted was filtered out. Is there a succinct way to do that using built-in functions from rxjs? For example:

```js
const isEven = (n) => n % 2 === 0;
const source = new BehaviorSubject(1);
const stream = source.pipe(filter(isEven));
stream.subscribe((n) => console.log(n)); // <- I want this to print `1`
source.next(2); // prints `2`; that's good
source.next(3); // does not print anything; that's good
```

I've written my own implementation, but would prefer a simpler solution using existing operators instead if it's easy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use a second BehaviorSubject

```js
const { BehaviorSubject } = rxjs;
const { filter} = rxjs.operators;

const isEven = (n) => n % 2 === 0;
const source = new BehaviorSubject(1);
const stream = new BehaviorSubject(source.getValue());

source.pipe(filter(isEven)).subscribe(stream);

stream.subscribe(val => { console.log(val); });
source.next(2);
source.next(3);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.4.0/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: OK, this is fairly simple. Cool. I think the middle part could be simplified to `source.pipe(filter(isEven)).subscribe(stream)`, too.

Comment: I realised that after I left work, it was late on a Friday afternoon and beer o'clock was calling.

Comment: How would you do this in such a way that if the filter is false, `stream` is assigned a default value instead simply not getting a new value at all?

Comment: It appears that I should use `map` instead of `filter` (pardon my newness to RxJS)

Answer (score 1):

Adrian's answer gets the credit, it looks like he answer the best way given the built-in operators available with `rxjs` itself. It didn't quite meet my needs, so I published my custom operator in my little library [`s-rxjs-utils`](https://github.com/simontonsoftware/s-rxjs-utils). It it called [`filterBehavior()`](https://simontonsoftware.github.io/s-rxjs-utils/typedoc/index.html#filterbehavior). From the docs:

> Works like `filter()`, but always lets through the first emission for each new subscriber. This makes it suitable for subscribers that expect the observable to behave like a `BehaviorSubject`, where the first emission is processed synchronously during the call to `subscribe()` (such as the `async` pipe in an Angular template).

Answer (score 0):

Your `stream` has already been piped to use the `isEven` filter, so your initial value of 1 is not shown in your console is behaving as expected.

If you want to see your initial value of 1, subscribe directly to the `BehaviourSubject`:

```
const isEven = (n) => n % 2 === 0;
const source = new BehaviorSubject(1);
const stream = source.pipe(filter(isEven));

// should print 1, and should print 2 and 3 when your source is nexted.
source.subscribe((n) => console.log(n)); 

stream.subscribe((n) => console.log(n)); // <- should NOT Print 1, because it has been filtered
source.next(2); // prints `2`; that's good
source.next(3); // does not print anything; that's good
```

Comment: Sorry - I must not be phrasing my question well. I know that's _why_ it's behaving differently, I want to know how to make it behave that way. I want to know how to construct `stream` such that it prints things at the times I listed. I'll go back to try rephrasing the question.