# RXJS Piped behavior subject

Tags: rxjs

I have a stream that is by default an empty object. Over time this object gets its keys filled.

```
  const RXSubject = new BehaviorSubject({});

  RXSubject.pipe(
    filter((frame): frame is InstDecodedFrame => frame.type === FrameType.INST),
    scan<InstDecodedFrame, InstantDataDictionnary>(
      (acc, frame) => ({ ...acc, ...frame.dataList }),
      {},
    ),
  );
```

Now I subscribe to the filter on some part of the app, but if I subscribe somewhere else and the last value has not been triggering the filter condition. My new observable just get nothing.

Is there any way that I get the latest "valid" value from the pipe in any of subscriber to the pipe ?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe this answer could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55526731/filtering-a-behaviorsubject

Answer (score 1):

You can use `shareReplay(1)` after `filter()` and subscribe to that observable:

```
const obs$ = RXSubject.pipe(
    filter((frame): frame is InstDecodedFrame => frame.type === FrameType.INST),
    scan<InstDecodedFrame, InstantDataDictionnary>(
      (acc, frame) => ({ ...acc, ...frame.dataList }),
      {},
    ),
    shareReplay(1),
  );
```

Then you'll subscribe to `obs$` instead of `RXSubject`.