# How to filter RXJS BehaviorSubject

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I want to filter data with BehaviorSubject.
When i try with:

```
   public accounts: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject(this.list); 
    this.accounts.pipe(filter((poiData: any) => {
      console.log(poiData)
    }));
```

No work and bellow (poiData: any) is line error with text:

> No overload matches this call.   Overload 1 of 2, '(predicate: (value:
> any, index: number) => value is any, thisArg?: any):
> OperatorFunction<any, any>', gave the following error.
> Argument of type '(poiData: any) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: any, index: number) => value is any'.

My question what is error ?
How to filter BehaviorSubject ?

Comment: `filter` must return a value. What if you add `return true;` after the console.log ?

Comment: RxJS `filter` != JS `filter`. They both different purposes. What exactly do you wish to do here?

Comment: Filter takes a predicate that decides which values are "kept". All I see here is a call to console.log, so it is hard to see what you're aiming to accomplish with `filter`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55526731/filtering-a-behaviorsubject

Comment: Please don't edit you post to change it to a completely different question. People spent time and answered your original question and by changing it you discredit their work. That's rude. If you have another question, feel free to [ask a new one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Answer (score 0):

Your error is occurring because the function you are passing to `filter()` returns `void` instead of a `boolean`.  You can resolve the error, but specifying an expression that evaluates to a boolean.

However, it looks like your BehaviorSubject emits an array:

```js
   public accounts: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject(this.list);
```

And it looks like your intention is to filter the array.  If this is the case, you don't want `filter` operator, because this will filter out emissions, which in your case, is the full array.  Since you want to filter the emitted array, you should use the rxjs `map` operator to map the emitted array to an array which you filter using the js `Array.prototype.filter` function, like this:

```
   public accounts: BehaviorSubject<any[]> = new BehaviorSubject(this.list); 
   public filteredAccounts = this.accounts.pipe(
        map(poiDataArray => poiDataArray.filter(
            acc => {
                console.log(acc);
                acc => acc.id != this.anyId;
            }
        ))
    );
```

Here is a simplified [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-66747015?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) example:

```js
  public numbers$ = new BehaviorSubject<number[]>([]);
  public oddNumbers$ = this.numbers$.pipe(
    // map to new array that filters out even numbers
    map(numbers => numbers.filter(n => n % 2)),
  );
```

Answer (score -1):

Your question doesn't make sense to me, but here some information that might help you solve your problem.

## Array#filter vs RxJS#filter

JS's filter on arrays in pretty similar to RxJS's filter on Observables (Remember that Subjects are observables too)

For example, consider this predicate that returns true if a number is even

```ts
const even = n => n % 2 == 0
```

These two pieces of code are pretty similar:

```ts
const arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
console.log(arr.filter(even));
```

Output: `[2,4,6,8]`

```ts
const arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
from(arr).pipe(
  filter(even)
).subscribe(console.log);
```

Output:

```html
2
4
6
8
```

In the first case, Array#filter returns an array where `even` returns true for every element in the array. The second version creates a stream where `even` returns true each element of the stream (after the filter).

Very similar.

## Predicates

A predicate is pretty easy to spot. It returns a boolean value. True or false.

```ts
(any) => true  // This is a predicate
(any) => false // this is a predicate
(any) => void  // this is not a predicate.
```

This:

```ts
(poiData: any) => {
  console.log(poiData);
}
```

is the same as `(any) => void`. So you cannot use this to filter either an array or an observable.

## Filtering an Observable vs Transforming an Observable

The most basic way you can transform an observable is with the `map` operator. Map changes the elements in your stream without effecting the stream directly (The number of emissions, their timing, ect).

It looks like maybe your observable is emitting an array (or list of some sort).

```ts
public accounts: BehaviorSubject<any> = 
  new BehaviorSubject(/* ---> */ this.list /* <--- */);
```

In this case, it's possible that you're not looking to alter the stream, but rather its elements. Perhaps that might look like this:

```ts
accounts.pipe(
  map(list => list.filter(element => /* code that returns true or false */))
).subscribe(console.log);
```

But, of course, you can filter the stream itself as well in order to decide if the list being held by your BehaviourSubject is emitted by the corresponding observable.

```ts
accounts.pipe(
  filter(list => /* code that returns true or false */)
).subscribe(console.log);
```

Comment: Yes this is work. list is key.. but one more question. Do I need to unsubscribe to this subscribe ?

Comment: Second question ...any time result in subscribe is good any time is emprty array [] ? Why what ? How